# Env var returning null in path

Tags: javascript, jenkins, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I have set up to ENV Vars (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
CERT_PATH=/home/ubuntu/certs/developer.cert.co.uk.pem
CA_PATH=/home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem
```

I am then grabbing those values in a JS script

```
var certPath = process.env.CERT_PATH;
var caPath = process.env.CA_PATH;
```

But I am stumped as to why one of the vars return `null` in the path:

```
-- console log here
CERT Path: null/certs/developer.cert.co.uk.pem
CA Path: /home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem
```

What I don't understand is the same setup on OSX does not have this issue.

Comment: What's the run-time context used to set the env vars?

Answer (score 2):

Though I cannot explain why i was getting null in my path, using the `withEnv` block around the relevant piece of my pipeline was what i ended up doing.

I normally do this but thought i could set the ENV var globally and be able to read from that without the need to so this, but seems to not be the case

```
withEnv(["CA_PATH=/home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem", "CERT_PATH=/home/ubuntu/certs/developer.cert.co.uk.pem"]) {
 try {
   sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
         run tests
      '''
     TESTS = 'success'
 } catch (Exception err) {
     TESTS = "failure"
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the pipeline groovy script simply use 
env.CERT_PATH = /home/ubuntu/certs/developer.cert.co.uk.pem